# Estándar para nombrar setters y getters

Tags: poo, funciones, estándares

**Actualización:**

¿Existe algún **estándar** que defina o recomiende alguna buena práctica para nombrar setters y getters?

---

Sobre todo en lenguajes OO, uno generalmente necesita hacer funciones que entreguen o que establezcan/actualicen el valor de un atributo. Estas funciones son llamadas en inglés: *setters* y *getters*.

Y por lo mismo, el nombre de cada una suele estar diferenciado por el prefijo correspondiente de tres letras (*set* y *get*).

Por ejemplo, para un atributo **meters**, tendríamos:

- `setMeters(val)`
- `getMeters()`

En español, ¿existe algún estándar definido para este caso?

Las opciones que he visto son:

- `establecerMetros()` y `obtenerMetros()`
- `estMetros()` y `obtMetros()`
- `setMetros()` y `getMetros()`

Comment: Creo que en general la programación en español (o algún otro lenguaje distinto del inglés) no está muy recomendada.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas abiertas no tienen respuestas concluyentes y objetivas y no son consideradas útiles en general en stackoverflow: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: En el caso se Java, por ejemplo, el uso de las palabras `get` y `set` son parte del Standard de JavaBeans. Si estuvieras escribiendo componentes, usar otra convención de nombres probablemente haría que tus componentes no funcionaran bien. Asimismo muchos IDEs funcionan siguiendo esta convención.

Comment: Creo que utilizar `get` y `set` es el estándar a pesar del _spanglish_. Yo particularmente uso nombres para identificadores en inglés también, creo que para no chocar con la sintaxis del lenguaje.

Comment: Lo que yo hago en particular es nunca programar en español, pues el inglés es casi siempre más conciso para sus términos. Pero de todas maneras hice la pregunta para ver qué tipo de discusión se generaba.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Se está preguntando _si existe algún estándar definido_, creo que a eso se puede responder objetivamente. Yo voto por reabrir la pregunta.

Comment: Ha quedado claro que esta pregunta es *offtopic*, pero yo mismo no puedo cerrarla dado que ya tiene respuestas (el sistema no me lo permite). Que los moderadores la cierren de una buena vez entonces.

Comment: Existen casos como este en el sitio en inglés y no veo que den puntos negativos o cierren la pregunta:

1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880321/angularjs-controller-service-naming-best-practice
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273695/git-branch-naming-best-practices

Aquí parece que están más deseosos por quitar puntos y criticar que por aportar.

Comment: Mi opinión es que la pregunta debe dejarse cerrada. La explicación la dejé en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26024110#26024110)

Answer (score 3):

La verdad no conzco ningún estándard oficial, pero de igual manera te propongo algunas sugerencias:

- Siempre es mejor un buen castellano a un mal inglés.
- Prefiere las opciones legibles, una variable llamada `int_auxb2` o `estValorDos` es menos entendible que `setTemporalSum` o `establecerSumaTemporal`.
- Usa `camel case` o el estándard de tu lenguaje extensivamente, los nombres de variables pueden ser inmensos y no por ello menos legibles, como por ejemplo `obtenerMetrosComoUnElementoDeCombo` o `suma_temporal`.
- Siempre documenta tu código en el lenguaje en que sea más factible que alguien lo lea con facilidad (incluido tú mismo).

Comment: Cualquier programa que tenga seriedad mínima debe de ser escrito en inglés. La razón es que nunca se sabe el alcance que tendrá, si va a ser mantenido por alguien que hable otro idioma, o si si tendrá colaboradores en otro idioma ( frances, aleman, japones, hindi etc. etc)

Comment: Pienso que estás en el lugar equivocado, este sitio fue creado porque no todo el mundo habla inglés, algunos estamos orgullosos de nuestra lengua vernácula y nos gustarían lenguajes de programación menos anglocéntrios, ampliando un poco en la línea de los no-lugares, donde va la gente lleva su cultura, es por lo tanto inevitable que las personas lleven su cultura a no-lugares como el Internet, sus códigos fuente, sus librerías, etc. No ser de gringolandia no puede ser un crímen, los hablantes de lenguas no anglosajonas también merecemos estándares incluyentes que contemplen nuestras lenguas.

Comment: Y los dos comentarios anteriores son *exactamente el motivo* de porque preguntas basadas en opinión son *off-topic* en toda la red [se] (c/c @Oscar)

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Entiendo tu opinión, yo mismo era así pero conservar la identidad y estar orgulloso de la propia cultura no tiene que estar en contra de ser **profesionales** y hacer bien nuestro trabajo. Actitudes como la tuya, aunque bien intencionadas son la causa (entre otras) de que estemos tan retrasados tecnológicamente. Olvida lo "ser de gringolandia" escribir el código en inglés te permite trabajar con Rusos y Franceses al mismo tiempo. StackOverflow en español es para facilitar el conocimiento, no para preservar la mirada obtusa y retrograda

Comment: @brasofilo De acuerdo, no debería ser un tema "controversial" y es una lástima que lo sea. Aún así no quería dejar pasar la oportunidad.

Comment: @OscarRyz, no tiene nada de retrograda usar tu propio lenguaje. Si los rusos y franceses trabajan para tí obviamente no será inconveniente, te lo comento porque donde trabajo se paga el soporte a RedHat Inc, y ni siquiera los extranjeros han tenido problemas con ello durante el proceso de QA. Una mirada obtusa y retrógrada es la que no contempla otros lenguajes y culturas diferentes, un proyecto con buen manejo de internacionalización debería de beneficiarse de la vastedad de los lenguajes en vez de perjudicarse.

Answer (score 2):

Para valores booleanos se considera buena práctica cambiar el nombre del getter a algo más legible como por ejemplo `isActive` o `hasProducts`

Comment: Pero en definitiva **no se traducen** a ningún idioma